# What is the safest way to merge a stable branch with the main Git branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, rebase

I have the following git branches.

**main  -> origin/main** (The local copy and origin/main are synchronized)
**dev/feature -> origin/dev_feature** (A stable branch that is 36 commits ahead of the main branch. local dev/feature and origin/dev_feature are synchronized)

Since origin/dev_feature is stable, I want to bring all the changes to origin/main. If there is a conflict, origin/dev_feature changes should take priority over origin/main. I am the only one working on this project. What is the safest way to merge all the changes to the main branch?

I'm thinking about doing the following.

```
git checkout dev/feature
git rebase main
```

if I understand it correctly, now my local main is pointing to the c2 and the feature is at c3.
c0 -> c1 -> c2 -> c3

```
git checkout master
git merge dev/feature
```

now both main and dev/features have the same set of changes.

```
git push origin main --force
```

Now the local copy and remote have the same set of changes.

Is this the correct way to do this? Are there any other safe alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: You stated "A stable branch that is 36 commits ahead of the main branch". That implies that it's also 0 commits *behind* `main`. Is that true, or is `main` also ahead of `dev/feature` by some number of commits? If `dev/feature` is fully ahead of `main` it isn't possible for there to be conflicts when you merge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. main is not ahead of dev/feature. So should I merge the changes as I described here?

Comment: You shouldn't consider any workflow where you have to use `force` safe :P. From what you have written it doesn't seem like you need it anyway. btw. you both use 'main' and 'master' in your text, I assume this is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario you described, with `dev/feature` being fully ahead of `main`, it won't be possible to have conflicts when you merge. So your steps would be, first checkout `main`:

```
git switch main # this is the same as the older command "checkout"
```

Now merge in `dev/feature` in one of two ways:

1. `git merge dev/feature`
2. `git merge dev/feature --no-ff`

Using #1 will "fast-forward" if possible, otherwise it will create a merge commit. Using #2 will force creating a merge commit even if fast-forward is possible. Note in your case a fast-forward is possible because `dev/feature` is fully ahead of `main`. (In other words the tip commit of `main` is in the history of `dev/feature`.)

Which merge type you choose is up to you, and they will both have the same *state*, but with different graphs. If you are deploying `main` to production and wish to maintain a history of each deployment you did, perhaps forcing the merge commit is helpful. Or, you could let it fast-forward and tag the commit that you deploy. Both are popular choices.

**Side Note:** if you let merging `dev/feature` into `main` do the fast-forward, it is identical to deleting `main`, and then creating a new branch called `main` from `dev/feature`. Another way of saying this is that branches are simply pointers to a commit, and when you merge with fast-forward you are simply repointing `main` to the commit that `dev/feature` is pointing to. Sometimes thinking about branches in this way helps conceptually.